# Redirect Joomla errors on Windows Azure IIS

Tags: azure, joomla, error-handling

I have a Joomla! site running on Windows Azure and all is fine.
But, everytime someone try do access something that not exist (www.domain.com/xpto) the server returns the error:

> jos-Warning: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unknown column 'header' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT `new_url`,`header`,`published` FROM `xxx_redirect_links` WHERE `old_url` = 'http://www.domain.com/xpto' LIMIT 0, 1' in

How can I redirect the user to the index everytime an error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Joomla, try to fix this by:

> Click on the Fix button in the Extension Manager -> Database page. If
>   that fails, a clean installation will need to be done.

ref: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/5953